# How can I modify the validity of a JwtSecurityToken?

Tags: c#, jwt, token

I create a JwtSecurityToken in my project.

```
SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(constant.securityKey));

Claim[] claims = new Claim[]
{
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name , constant.tokenClaim)
};

JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
    claims: claims,
    notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
);

return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
```

But I wanted to know if it's possible modify the validity of the token after its creation?

Comment: what do you mean by validity? corrupt the information, or say in it is an invalid token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is a simple "No". The line:

```
signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
```

indicates that the JWT is being signed using a [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), so any change to any value in the token after creation will mean that the payload and the signature will not match, and the token will be invalid.

You can always give the token a short lifetime, and require a frequent refresh of  it if you need to change the contents

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a token without resigning it again. 
So in fact you always need to create a new token.

This is usually called silent refresh.  Some check is done to see if the token is near it's expiration. If so, a new token is requested normally ( or you make it apparantly).

So if you give out a token to somebody, they can not create a valid token without the certificate.

If you need OAuth 2.0 functionality, please check out open source project IdentityServer